# Delete specific string from column in sqlite

Tags: sql, sqlite

My column (time_stamp) contains DATE and TIME in a single column. I want to delete TIME then I will be able to group records according to date. but I don't know how to delete just time from a below column. 
The query

```
delete time_stamp from table1  // deletes whole column but I just want to delete time not date from column.
```

```
time_stamp
 2018-09-01 05:02:08
 2018-09-01 05:05:21
 2018-09-01 05:12:08
 2018-09-01 05:22:08
```

Is that possible?

Comment: I don't get what a time column has to do with aggregation.  I would suggest that you ask a *new* question with sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what you want to accomplish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`date()`](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-date-functions/sqlite-date-function/) or [`substr()`](http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/sqlite-functions/sqlite-substr/) in the `group by` clause:

```
group by date(time_stamp)
```

or

```
group by substr(time_stamp, 1, 10)
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
UPDATE table1 SET time_stamp = date(time_stamp);
```